# Get all instance methods on top of the class definition

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to wrap all instance methods of `TestClass` to perform code *before* and *after* an instance method is called. So far, this code is working:

```
module Wrapper
  def wrap(*methods)
    prependable_module = Module.new do
      methods.each do |m|
        define_method(m) do |*args, &block|
          p 1
          super(*args, &block)
          p 3
        end
      end
    end

    prepend prependable_module
  end
end

class TestClass
  extend Wrapper
  wrap :instance_method1

  def instance_method1
    p 2
  end
end

TestClass.new.instance_method1 # => 1, 2, 3
```

I can call `wrap` with all method names as arguments. If I try to wrap all methods without listing them individually, I need to call it using `instance_methods(false)` at the bottom of the class definition.

```
class TestClass
  extend Wrapper
    
  def instance_method1
    p 2
  end
  
  wrap(*instance_methods(false))
end
```

In Rails, all callback methods like `before_action` or `after_create` are usually called on top of the class definition. **My goal is to call `wrap` on top of the class definition** as well (without listing all methods individually). In this case, I can't call `instance_methods(false)` on top of the class definition, because at this point no method has been defined.

Thanks for your help!

## Update

Thanks to [Kimmo Lehto's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52944676/4942323) approach I can wrap every instance method using the `method_added` hook. I don't want to prepend a new module for every defined method, so I add all overridden methods to the same module.

```
module Wrapper
  def method_added(method_name)
    tmp_module = find_or_initialize_module
    return if tmp_module.instance_methods(false).include?(method_name)

    tmp_module.define_method(method_name) do |*args, &block|
      p 1
      super(*args, &block)
      p 3
    end
  end

  def find_or_initialize_module
    module_name  = "#{name}Wrapper"
    module_idx   = ancestors.map(&:to_s).index(module_name)

    unless module_idx
      prepend Object.const_set(module_name, Module.new)
      return find_or_initialize_module
    end

    ancestors[module_idx]
  end
end

class TestClass
  extend Wrapper

  def instance_method1
    p 2
  end
end

tc = TestClass.new
tc.instance_method1 # => 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: Please (edit to) clarify "function executions" in the first sentence.

Comment: Note: Ruby uses two spaces for indentation.

Comment: In the first case you're calling `wrap` before the method's defined, in the second after. Does this have something to do with the difference?

Comment: In the first case I'm calling `wrap` with hard coded arguments. But I want to call `wrap` without listing all method names individually. `instance_methods(false)` returns an array of all defined instance_method names of a class. But If I call `instance_methods(false)` on top of the class definition, it returns an empty array because the methods are not defined yet - the are getting defined below. If I call it at the bottom of the class, it will work because the methods have been defined above.

Comment: This is, presumably, instrumentation for testing. Does it make sense to call `wrap instance_methods(false)` inside the class definition? Would it instead normally be called on the class by something testing the class? `wrap TestClass, TestClass.instance_methods(false)`?

Comment: I want to use it for error handling and logging. And I want to use the wrapper like a Rails callback.. I see your point, but I need to call wrap inside of the class definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Module#method_added](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Module.html#method-i-method_added) hook to automatically wrap any methods that are added.

You will need some magic to not get a stack overflow from an infinite loop.

Another option is to use [TracePoint](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/TracePoint.html) to trigger the wrapping once the class has been defined. You can use the `Module#extended` to set up the tracepoint. Something like:

```
module Finalizer
  def self.extended(obj)
    TracePoint.trace(:end) do |t|
      if obj == t.self
        obj.finalize
        t.disable
      end
    end
  end

  def finalize
    wrap(*instance_methods(false))
  end
end
```

Classes are usually not exactly "closed" unless you explicitly `.freeze` them so it's a bit of a hacky solution and will not trigger if methods are added afterwards. `method_added` is probably your best bet.

Comment: The `method_added` hook worked for me! Thank you so much. I will update my post with my current solution within the next hours.